# Develop Extensions for Magento Enterprise edition is same as Community edition?

Tags: magento-1.9

I wan to know, how to develop extension in magento Enterprise Edition ? is this same as Community Edition or some major or minor differences.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as developing for CC.
The only differences are the things EE has that CC does not have. Full Page Cache for instance.